# Python call a method from a string

Tags: python

I am trying to call a method from a string in python. However, I need that method to print the return of that method. I am currently using

```
print (getattr(object, x)
```

where x is the string and object is the modudle/class.
However it is not printing the return statement for some reason, is this not possible with getattr?

Comment: Here's the code sorry should have added to main one
http://pastebin.com/swpc70yz
http://pastebin.com/rM1iZJJB

Comment: @user6435: please provide a *minimal working example*. Something that can be used by people to do debugging and *show* that their solution works.

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Edit your question to include the code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need

```
 print (   getattr(getCommand, x)()  )
```

`getattr` gets you the method, but it doesn't call it. That's done by the additional `()`

Also, you have an unclosed open bracket in your code.